# Callback fires before iteration is complete

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using the [async](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html) library in this project. One function (copied below) includes a nested loop to build a 2D Array. The callback is called before the array is completely built. I'd really like to understand why this is happening and learn more about best practices. What is the best way to solve this problem?

```
function getStopTimesForTrips(cb) {
        timeTable.listOfTripIds.forEach(function(id){
            retrieveTimesByTrip(id, function(err, st){
                var tempArray = [];
                st.forEach(function(st){
                    tempArray.push(st.arrival_time);
                });
                timeTable.stopTimes.push(tempArray);
            });
        });
        // cb(null, timeTable); <- This line fires the callback before we finish building the array. 
        setTimeout(function(){cb(null, timeTable);},2500); // This effective solution is poor form. What's the correct way to solve this issue? 
    }
```

Comment: You're not even using `async` methods provided by the library.

Comment: Looks like a loop of asyncronous functions, but you call you callback without waiting for them all to be called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to be using any function from the `async` library. The correct solution is to use `async`:

```
async.each(timeTable.listOfTripIds,function(id,cb2){
    retrieveTimesByTrip(id, function(err, st){
        var tempArray = [];
        st.forEach(function(st){
            tempArray.push(st.arrival_time);
        });
        timeTable.stopTimes.push(tempArray);
        cb2(err); // Need to call this to tell async this iteration
                  // is done. Think of it as an async "return".
    });
},function(err){
    // if we're here it means the `async.each` is done:
    cb(null, timeTable);
});
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to just use native promises and wait for the async calls to finish

```
function getStopTimesForTrips(cb) {
    var promises = timeTable.listOfTripIds.map(function(id) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            retrieveTimesByTrip(id, function(err, st) {
                if (err) return reject();
                timeTable.stopTimes = st.map(function(item) {
                    return item.arrival_time;
                }));
                resolve();
            });
        });
    });

    Promise.all(promises).then(function() {
        cb(null, timeTable);
    });
}
```

Just making the entire function thenable would be better

```
function getStopTimesForTrips() {
    return Promise.all(
        timeTable.listOfTripIds.map(function(id) {
            return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                retrieveTimesByTrip(id, function(err, st) {
                    if (err) return reject();
                    resolve(
                        st.map(function(item) {
                            return item.arrival_time;
                        })
                    );
                });
            });
        })
    );
}

getStopTimesForTrips().then(function(arrival_times) { ... })
```